spfx - ListView control adding contextual menu using functional component
I am creating a webpart using functional components rather than class components. I am using the ListView Control that is part of this package:office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ContextualMenu. I only see 1 example that is not using a class component on the web.
I am able to render the data in the ListView component, but I am having problems with the click event for the context menu. The error I am getting with the second  "i" reference.
The error message is:
Argument of type 'IContextualMenuItem | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContextualMenuItem'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IContextualMenuItem

Example of where the problem is located
onClick: (e, i) => **_handleClick(i, props.item.CaseID + ' Case ID')**

My component code is below.
import * as React from 'react';
import { Layer, IconButton, IButtonProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { ContextualMenuItemType, IContextualMenuItem } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ContextualMenu';
import styles from './ListViewDemoWebPart.module.scss';

export interface IContextMenuProps {
    item: any;
    i:IContextualMenuItem;
}

const ListViewContextMenu: React.FC<IContextMenuProps> = (props) => {

    const _handleClick = (item: IContextualMenuItem, msg: string): void => {
        console.log(`Key: ${item.key} - Argument: ${msg}`);
    };

    return (
        <div >
            <IconButton id='ContextualMenuButton1'
                text=''
                width='25'
                split={false}
                iconProps={{ iconName: 'MoreVertical' }}
                menuIconProps={{ iconName: '' }}
                menuProps={{
                    shouldFocusOnMount: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            key: 'View',
                            name: 'View Case',
                            onClick: (e, i) => **_handleClick(i, props.item.CaseID + ' Case ID')**
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'divider_1',
                            itemType: ContextualMenuItemType.Divider
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'edit',
                            name: 'Edit Case',
                            onClick: (e, i) => _handleClick(i, props.item.CaseStatus + ' Case Status')
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'share',
                            name: 'Share Case',
                            onClick: (e, i) => _handleClick(i, props.item.BizSegment + ' Business Segment')
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'delete',
                            name: 'Delete Case',
                            disabled: true,
                            onClick: () => console.error('Disabled action should not be clickable.')
                        }
                    ]
                }} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ListViewContextMenu;


I figured it out. I added a property "i" and set it to any. Then I passed it to the component as props.i.

I figured it out. I added a property "i" and set it to any. Then I passed it to the component as props.i.
export interface IContextMenuProps {
    item: any;
    i:any;
}

onClick: (e, i) => _handleClick(props.i, props.item.CaseID + ' Case ID')

